# How to submit an update for an older (compatibility) version of an app on the AppStore - iOS?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Apple AppStore makes in possible for users who don't or can't run the minimum required version iOS by an app to download an older version of the app that's compatible with their device (if available).

The user is presented a question:

**The current version requires iOS 15.0 or later, but you can download the last compatible version.**

This is great, but I'm in an awkward situation that I need to issue a patch to my 'old' users who are running an older version of the app because of a third-party API change.

I don't want to patch the old version and just submit it as a new one to the AppStore because that would effectively downgrade all of my 'new' users who are running a much newer version of the app and just happen to click the 'Update' button in the meantime.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: No, there’s no way to update an old version, you can only release new versions.

Comment: Thanks. This must cause a lot of head ache to other developers, as well :(

Comment: You can however change which versions are available for the last compatible version redownload, so you can prevent people from downloading a broken version.

Comment: @JordanH I understand, this way I could make it work: 1) upload a new version from the **old** code base (fix for old users) and make it immediately unavailable. 2) upload a new version from the **new** code base 3) then make both available. This way both 'compatibility' users and new users could enjoy an updated version. Is that assumption correct?

Comment: You cannot make the current version unavailable to download for new users, but otherwise I think it’d work.